# label not working with checkbox

Tags: html

OK, what am I missing?
I have:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="showRatings" value="1" checked>
    <label for="showRatings">Show Ratings</label>
</form>
```

And when I click on the "Show Ratings" text, the checkbox is not toggling.
I know it's something simple.

Comment: @Phillip [The HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) defines how the `for` attribute works. In case you didn't notice, my first comment above is a link to the exact paragraph in the standard where the `for` attribute is defined.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Thanks.  That's a neat blog viewer you've made.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I believe the `label` element links to the `id` attribute, not the `name` attribute.  Try this:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="showRatings" id="showRatings" value="1" checked>
  <label for="showRatings">Show Ratings</label>
</form>
```

Reference [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1).

Comment: Oh, dang it! That's it! Thanks David!

Comment: I had this problem, looks like the label section has to be after the input section

Comment: The label does not need to be after or before, it really doesn't matter. But what does matter (and stumped me for a while) is you need to double double check that there's no duplicate ID's or labels. There could be one accidentally generated or placed somewhere. So open up Chrome inspector and do a quick search to make sure.

Comment: @JoelWorsham: Well, duplicate IDs would be invalid markup so at that point all behavior is undefined.  So you'll definitely want to make sure there are no duplicate IDs in any DOM, whether using labels or not :)

Comment: @David Yes definitely, that's my point. Sometimes one may slip in there though accidentally ;)

Comment: I found another control with the same id that was causing the issue.

Comment: Also please keep in mind, that you need to have `value` in your markup. Without it label is not clickable

Answer (score 20):

When input element is inside the label then we do not need id on the element and 'for' attribute on the label, but when it is outside we need it.

```
<label>
    Foo
    <input name="foo" type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

Clicking on "Foo" will trigger a toggle of the checkbox

Comment: This will work even without 'name'/'id' attribute for input. ie Checkbox that you don't want to be part of the form

Answer (score 1):

try this this will work. it will not work with name attribute.

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="showRatings" id="showRatings" value="1" checked>
  <label for="showRatings">Show Ratings</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).